# Loading external module to Intern.js config file

Tags: javascript, functional-testing, intern

I've been working with Intern.js and I wanted to add a server check before the tests run, to check that the server is running and also that it's running in test mode.

To do that I created a function that makes a GET request to my API and checks if there was any response and if it was the right response. I added it to my setup function in my intern config file, before any of the tests ran. For that I used the http module from npm.

Now, the problem I ran into is that if I require another module other than "intern" itself in the intern.js config file, I get errors.

My workaround for that was to define an auxiliary module inside of the setup function and require the http module from there.

I wanted to know if there is any other solution and if this may be an issue with intern itself.